# Iterate grouping in angular. How do I display the key

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have this groupItem in my controller

```
var groupedItem = returnItem.GroupBy(x => x.Goal).AsQueryable();
```

This is what the groupItem look like

```
[
{"Goal":"X","Task":""A,"TaskArgument":null},
{"Goal":"X","Task":"B","TaskArgument":null},
{"Goal":"X","Task":"B","TaskArgument":null},
]

[
{"Goal":"Y","Task":"A","TaskArgument":null},

]
```

This is what I see in html for

```
<ul  ng-repeat="(s,t) in groupedItem">
        Group name: {{ s }}

        <li ng-repeat="st in t">
            each one: {{ st.Task }}
        </li>
    </ul>

Group name:0
each one: A
each one: B
each one: B
Group name:1
each one: A
```

How do I display the Group Name ( X and Y) ? If I have {{s.Goal}} there is no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul ng-repeat="(s,t) in groupedItem">
        Group name: {{ t[0].Goal }}

        <li ng-repeat="st in t">
            each one: {{ st.Task }}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This solution relies on the fact that no group is empty.

Comment: I also see that the grouping was wrong. It should be    var map = returnItem.GroupBy(x => x.Goal).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList()); Using your answer and this dictionary, works. Thanks